# Como retornar key de objeto com maior valor em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Digamos que eu tenha o seguinte objeto:

```
var obj = {"frutas": 50, "vegetais": 100, "carnes": 150 };
```

Como eu conseguiria retornar a chave do item de maior valor? Exemplo:

```
obj.maxKey(); // "carnes"
```

Eu testei algumas funções que tratam de arrays, mas aparentemente elas não funcionam com objetos no padrão `key: value`, exemplo:

```
Math.max.apply(null, meuArrayAqui);
```

Então, **como eu conseguiria retornar a key do item de maior valor**?

Comment: Aceita a utilização de frameworks?

Comment: @Fernando jQuery sim, mas não plugins de terceiros.

Comment: uhm! tava pensando [nesse](http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq), mas agora que percebi que em seu caso não é um array e sim um objeto, e esse só funciona para array? Ou pode ser com array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe função nativa para isso, então você terá de verificar todos os valores para encontrar o maior:

```js
var obj = { "frutas": 50, "vegetais": 100, "carnes": 150 };
var maior = -Infinity;
var chave;
for (var prop in obj) {
  // ignorar propriedades herdadas
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    if (obj[prop] > maior) {
      maior = obj[prop];
      chave = prop;
    }
  }
}
console.log(chave);
```

O princípio é esse. Claro que para um uso real é melhor embrulhar isso numa função. Dependendo do uso desejado, pode-se ainda fazer algumas otimizações.

Comment: Ótima resposta, escolhi ela como correta por não necessitar de bibliotecas de terceiros e por não persistir os valores do objeto em caso de reuso da função.

Answer (score 4):

A maneira mais simples me parece ser com um loop mesmo, mas se você busca uma alternativa mais funcional, isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

- Obter todas as chaves do objeto, usando [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys);
- Ordená-las por ordem decrescente de valor (é preciso usar uma função customizada pra isso);
- Pegar o primeiro elemento.

Exemplo:

```js
var obj = {"frutas": 50, "vegetais": 100, "carnes": 150 };

var maior = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b) {
                return obj[a] > obj[b] ? -1 :
                       obj[b] > obj[a] ? 1 : 0;
            })[0];

document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "<p>" + maior + "</p>";
```

Comment: [Fiz um teste](http://jsperf.com/sopt-54600) e descobri que isso é bem lento. Mais lento que usar jQuery para o loop.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não me surpreende, dado que ordenação é `n*log(n)`, enquanto as demais são só `n`... Se o AP não tivesse explicitamente dito que não queria frameworks de terceiros, eu sugeriria o [`_.max`](http://underscorejs.org/#max), que permite estabelecer um critério arbitrário para o max sem precisar fazer operações desnecessárias. De todo modo, um loop simples deve ser mais rápido que qualquer alternativa mais sofisticada.

Comment: É, o underscore foi a primeira coisa que pensei. [Talvez em ES7 (!) haja um `Object.values`](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2014-04/apr-9.md#51-objectentries-objectvalues), aí daria pra fazer algo mais limpo (o que é uma grande qualidade da sua solução).

Answer (score 3):

Usando o `each` do jQuery e percorrendo por todos os objetos, pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
function getKeyOfMaxObjValue(obj){
  // Variável que armazenará a maior key.
  var key;
  // Variável auxiliar para checar os valores
  var value = 0;
  $.each(obj, function(idx, val){
    // Se o valor atual da iteração é maior que o auxiliar
    if(val > value){
      // Atualiza o valor da variável auxiliar
      value = val;
      // Atribue a nova key
      key = idx;
    }
  });
  return key;
}
```

Comment: Solução bem limpa, mas quando eu uso a função seguidamente com um objeto de valores diferentes, ele continua retornando o resultado do primeiro objeto que usei.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu testei **[nesse pen](http://codepen.io/Kazzkiq/pen/MYzEoY)**, mas acabei substituindo pela solução marcada como "correta" por causa do problema mencionado acima. Você pode trocar a função de lá por essa para reproduzir o que comentei.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Realmente, re-testei aqui e o erro não reproduziu de novo, engraçado que foi só mudar a função que ele tinha sumido da primeira vez. Enfim, vou remover os comentários.